# GE plugin tethered placemark

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I am trying to code a tethered `placemark` in the plugin just like the ones in google earth but I can't find any reference to a single line going from ground up to the pushpin. 
Here is what I have so far: what am I missing?

```
var placemark = ge.createPlacemark("");
var point = ge.createPoint("");
point.setLatitude(41.0);
point.setLongitude(-88.0);
placemark.setGeometry(point);
point.setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
point.setAltitude(500);
ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the [extrude property](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#point) of the KML point to true. i.e.

```
point.setExtrude(true);
```

This specifies whether to connect the geometry to the ground with a "tail" as you require.

It is also worth noting that for `extrude` to have any effect the `altitudeMode` of the `point` must be either `relativeToGround`, `relativeToSeaFloor`, or `absolute`.

Also, you can set the properties of the point using the shorthand `set` method. i.e.

```
// latitude, longitude, altitude, altitudeMode, extrude, tessellate 
point.set(41, -88, 500, ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND, true, false);
```